# Implementing POSIX file mode library

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system, posix

I implemented a [virtual file system library](https://github.com/HOMEINFO/vfslib/blob/c01abe9f941516d1afebf01da4449213d935f1cb/vfslib.py) with POSIX file mode representation.
Any suggestions regarding optimization are welcome.

```
"""POSIX file system library."""

from collections import namedtuple

__all__ = ['PosixPermission', 'PosixMode']


MIN_PERM = 0b000
MAX_PERM = 0b111
DEF_PERM = 0b110    # rw-
MIN_MODE = 0o000
MAX_MODE = 0o777
DEF_MODE = 0o640


class PosixPermission(namedtuple('PosixPermission', 'read write execute')):
    """POSIX file permissions."""

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, perm=DEF_PERM):
        """Creates the file permissions from the respective integer value."""
        if MIN_PERM <= perm <= MAX_PERM:
            return cls(bool(perm & 4), bool(perm & 2), bool(perm & 1))

        raise ValueError('Permission value must be between {} and {}.'.format(
            MIN_PERM, MAX_PERM))

    def __int__(self):
        """Returns the integer value of the file permission."""
        return (self.read and 4) + (self.write and 2) + (self.execute and 1)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns binary representation of the file permission."""
        return ''.join(map(
            lambda perm: perm or '-',
            (self.read and 'r', self.write and 'w', self.execute and 'x')))


class PosixMode(namedtuple('PosixMode', 'user group other')):
    """POSIX file mode."""

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, mode=DEF_MODE):
        """Creates the file mode from the respective integer value."""
        if MIN_MODE <= mode <= MAX_MODE:
            return cls(
                PosixPermission.from_int(mode >> 6 & 7),
                PosixPermission.from_int(mode >> 3 & 7),
                PosixPermission.from_int(mode & 7))

        raise ValueError('File mode must be between {} and {}.'.format(
            oct(MIN_MODE), oct(MAX_MODE)))

    def __int__(self):
        """Returns the integer value of the file mode."""
        return (int(self.user) << 6) + (int(self.group) << 3) + int(self.other)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the octal representation of the file mode."""
        return ''.join((str(self.user), str(self.group), str(self.other)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused why you're using a named tuple for `PosixPermission`. To me an Enum would be a better choice:

```
class PosixPermission(Flag):
    READ = 4
    WRITE = 2
    EXECUTE = 1
    NONE = 0

    @property
    def perms(self):
        return ''.join(
            name if self & val else '-'
            for name, val in zip('rwx', PosixPermission)
        )
```

```
>>> PosixPermission(0)
<PosixPermission.NONE: 0>
>>> PosixPermission(7)
<PosixPermission.READ|WRITE|EXECUTE: 7>
>>> PosixPermission(5)
<PosixPermission.READ|EXECUTE: 5>
>>> PosixPermission(5).perms
'r-x'
>>> PosixPermission(5) & PosixPermission.READ
<PosixPermission.READ: 4>
>>> PosixPermission(5) & PosixPermission.WRITE
<PosixPermission.NONE: 0>
>>> PosixPermission(8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: 8 is not a valid PosixPermission
```

---

Honestly `PosixMode` looks pretty good, I think it's reasonable to assume it to be a `namedtuple`, rather than an `object` with `__slots__`. I however wouldn't use `__int__` and `__str__`, and would instead use properties for these.

Comment: I do not understand your enum approach. How would I get a permission instance of, let's say `r-x` (read, *not* write, execute) with it?

Comment: @RichardNeumann As demonstrated above, `PosixPermission(5)`.

Comment: Ah. Got it. But then I could not do `if posix_mode.user.write` without adding the `write` property, which I already have on the namedtuple.

Comment: @RichardNeumann You can however use `if posix_mode.user & PosixPermission.WRITE`. If you don't like the length of it, you can just make `PosixPermission.WRITE` a variable, and use `if posix_mode.user&WRITE`.

Comment: @MaartenFabré That's exactly what I meant to say in my last comment.

Comment: I just noticed, that `enum.Flag` is not yet available in python 3.4 which the system in question is running. So `enum.Flag`, unfortunately, is not an option.

Comment: @RichardNeumann You should be able to use [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) which is produced by the same person that made the `enum` standard library.